# How I can install varnish cache in my app openshift?

Tags: caching, openshift, varnish

I need to install and set up step by step the varnish cache in an application in OpenShift , but I do not know where to start and not the steps for this. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean OpenShift Online in current production version, it's older version 2.x, based on RedHat's own container technology.

If you have OpenShift Origin or OpenShift Enterprise or OpenShift Online Developer Preview, probably it's version 3.x, and it's based on Docker.

You can definitely tell which version are you using by looking at CLI tool's name. If it's **rhc**, it's older version 2.x, if it's **oc**, it's newer Docker based.

For newer Docker base, you should be able to deploy any docker image, so varnish should be no problem at all.
You just have to build your own docker image and follow OpenShift tutorial to deploy it on your platform.
I started to play with it, but don't have enough know-how to provide you with step-by-step tutorial right now, maybe in a week or so.

However, if you are using older public version of OpenShift Online, I have a bad news for you.
I've tried to compile static version of *varnishd*, no luck till now. And I'm not going to try anymore, because fully static version of *varnishd* is not possible at all, as it's based on dynamically loading of compiled VCLs, thus should be dynamically linked to OS libraries.
And this could be a bit hard to achieve. You have to match correct versions of OS libraries and still it's fragile as it could possibly break after upgrade of underlying OS.

I wouldn't try this in production.

I suggest you to try another could provider, either IaaS solution with full OS with varnishd installed from packages, or choose any Docker hosting provider.

Or, if you can afford it and it's worth for you, you may try http://fastly.com/, a CDN provider.
Their technology is based on customized older version of varnishd, with easy to use GUI, a lot of fancy built-in stats, etc... But the most important feature is you can deploy your own VCLs upon request. If they enable it to you, you can upload new VCL in few seconds.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, my version of openshift uses cli rhc, and I managed to install the cartridge, but cannot monitor anything using varnishncsa, redhat simply nor recognizes the command. I managed to configure the default.vcl to point to my url but don't know if it was working.

Comment: Where did you get that cartridge from? I haven't found anything ready-made, so I was trying to compile it from sources as fully statically linked binary. But as I said, I stopped this activity after I've realized it's silly idea to statically compile executable which uses `dlopen()` explicitly.

Comment: Hi, Rastislav. I found here: https://github.com/devop-mmcgrath/openshift-cartridge-varnish

Comment: Whoa, quite a hack! But thanks for great stuff for studying OpenShift v2 internals. :) Nonetheless, could you please try this command? `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$OPENSHIFT_VARNISH_DIR/usr/lib64/varnish/:$OPENSHIFT_VARNISH_DIR/usr/lib64/" varnishncsa -n $OPENSHIFT_VARNISH_DIR/var/lib/varnish`. This should run `varnishncsa` in foreground being connected to running varnish instance.

Comment: Hi There,
where I can put this command line ? In the SSH terminal ? on my server varnish ? Sorry but it's the first time I try to do this !!

Comment: open ssh session to your gear a run it there. you can connect either with blueprinted ssh command line in openshift web-console (open application detail page, click on _Want to log in to your application?_ under _Remote Access_ caption and use ssh command shown) or you can use `rhc ssh -a {your app name}`, it's probably `rhc ssh -a varnish` in your case.

Comment: Thanks Rastislav!!